# Return value from react component

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a react app, and I must to build a custmon dropdonw component, I need that my component returns the selected value.

I know the starndad way (or I think is the best way but, may be better if you know)

```
const getSelectedValue = (value) => {
 console.log(value);
}

const component = <Dropdonw valueList={list} getSelectedValue={getSelectedValue} />
```

Is there any way to return de value using a variable or the javascript way  `component.options[e.selectedIndex].value`. For example

```
const component = <Dropdonw valueList={list} />

...
<code>
...

console.log(component.getSelectedValue());
```

Could you tell me if there are others ways to get or return values, or the standard and best way y passing a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a single value from a react component. What you can do is lift the state up:

*Parent:*

```
const [dropdownVal, setDropdownVal] = useState(null)

<MyDropdown valueList={list} setDropdownVal={setDropdownVal} dropdownVal={dropdownVal} />
```

*MyDropdown:*

```
export const MyDropdown = ({valueList, dropdownVal, setDropdownVal}} => {

  return(
    <Dropdown valueList={valueList} value={dropdownVal} onChange={/* get value and call setDropdownVal */} />
  )

}
```